# change class of anchor onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have dynamic list of `a` tags. I have bind them with a `onclick` function. I want to change the class of that tag to `active` inside `onclick` function.

```
list = list + "<li><a href='#' onclick='gotochapter(" + index + ")'><i class='fa fa-square-o'></i>Chapter-" + val.Chapter_Name + "</a></li>";
listdiv.append(list);

function gotochapter(index) {
    console.log(contentlist[index].Chapter_Name);
    $(this).addClass("active");
}
```

But this is not working.

Comment: Instead of `onClick('gotochapter("+index+")')` try `onClick='gotochapter("+index+")'`

Comment: sorry I have improved the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main issue is that when using an `on*` event attribute, the scope of the function will be the `window`, not the clicked element, hence `this` does not refer to what you expect.

To fix the issue, and tidy your logic, you can use an unobtrusive event handler instead:

```
// in a loop:
list = list + '<li><a href="#" data-index="' + index + '"><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>Chapter-' + val.Chapter_Name + '</a></li>';

// outside the loop:
listdiv.on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  var index = $(this).addClass("active").data('index');
  console.log(contentlist[index].Chapter_Name);
}).append(list);
```

Comment: I suspect `listdiv` to be a JS object, fetched with `getElementById`, and it may not have the jQuery `.on` method.

Comment: That's possible. OP would need to use `$(listdiv)` in that case

Comment: Its working but now I have to remove active  from anchor tags which are clicked before :P

Comment: Call this just after `preventDefault()`: `$('.active').removeClass('active')`

Answer (score 1):

```
list = list + "<li><a href='#' onclick='gotochapter(" + index + " , this)'><i class='fa fa-square-o'></i>Chapter-" + val.Chapter_Name + "</a></li>"
  listdiv.append(list);
function gotochapter(index , obj)
{
    console.log(contentlist[index].Chapter_Name);
    $(obj).addClass("active");


}   // Pass this as argument
```

Comment: I only want to add this class to particular anchor which is clicked

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way to go. Use event delegation for dynamically added elements.

```
var $listdiv = $("#listdiv")

$listdiv.on("click", "a", function(){
     $(this).addClass("active")
})

$listdiv.append("<a href='#'>Some link</a>")
```

This code will work with present and future `<a>`.